# How to parse xml string with namespace using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have an xml which is :

```
<ns1:GetStudentDataCollection xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns1:GetStudentData>
<ns1:RecordID>1</ns1:RecordID>
<ns1:StudentID>1</ns1:StudentID>
<ns1:StudentName>Arzon</ns1:StudentName>
<ns1:Class>2</ns1:Class>
<ns1:FathersName>Peter John</ns1:FathersName>
<ns1:MothersName>Maria John</ns1:MothersName>
</ns1:GetStudentData>
</ns1:GetStudentDataCollection>
```

this xml is in a variable which i am converting to xmlDoc as:

```
var xmlDoc=StringtoXML(xmlString);
```

//After getting xmlDoc i am trying to read the xml contents
    Readxml(xmlDoc);

```
//converts string to xml
function StringtoXML(text){
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
      var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
      doc.async='false';
      doc.loadXML(text);
    } else {
      var parser=new DOMParser();
      var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
    }
    return doc;
}
```

At Readxml() function i am doing like this :

```
function Readxml(xmlDoc) {

x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('RecordID');
console.log(x.length);
alert("Value of x is : " + x);
}
```

But when i run the above thing i am not getting any value of x. So this means that i am not able to parse this xml. What am i doing wrong. Please help. Looking forward to you solutions.

Comment: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('RecordID')` return array like object .. to print its value .. you should use .. `x[0].innerHTML`

Comment: but if xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('RecordID') returns array then it should atleast give me length. But when i print its length it gives me 0

Answer (score -1):

You can parse xml with help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library .

```
var xml = ['<ns1:GetStudentDataCollection xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">',
'<ns1:GetStudentData>',
'<ns1:RecordID>1</ns1:RecordID>',
'<ns1:StudentID>1</ns1:StudentID>',
'<ns1:StudentName>Arzon</ns1:StudentName>',
'<ns1:Class>2</ns1:Class>',
'<ns1:FathersName>Peter John</ns1:FathersName>',
'<ns1:MothersName>Maria John</ns1:MothersName>',
'</ns1:GetStudentData>',
'</ns1:GetStudentDataCollection>'].join('');

console.log( $( xml ).find('ns1\\:RecordID').text() )
```

which prints `1` .

Comment: Thanks for the reply rab, but the above xml is just a small part of the actual one. I am getting this xml by invoking a webservice and then i am storing this response in a variable and after that i am doing all the above coding to parse this xml